# How to iterate through a dictionary to get and pass key name to string

Tags: c#, json, algorithm, dictionary, data-structures

I'd like to iterate through a C# dictionary storing nested JSON to retrieve and pass the dictionary key name to a string, in the form of "key1:key1-1:key1-1-1".

After that, a new dictionary is created to use the specially arranged string as its keys.

Finally, desiredDictionary["key:key:key"] = originalDictionary["key"]["key"]["key"].

Please make the answer specific, my apology that I'm new to C# IEnumerable class and JSON.

I've stored the JSON data into a dictionary, the sample JSON is given below.

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

......
string jsonText = File.ReadAllText(myJsonPath);
var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();

//this is the dictionary storing JSON
var dictJSON = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(jsonText); 

//this is the dictionary with keys of specially arranged string 
var desiredDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
......
......
//Here is a sample JSON
{
    "One": "Hey",

    "Two": {
        "Two": "HeyHey"
           }

     "Three": {
        "Three": {
            "Three": "HeyHeyHey"    
                 }
              } 
}
```

I need help with the process for dictionary key name retrieval, string completion, and new dictionary value passing.
According to the given JSON, desiredDict["Three:Three:Three"] = dictJSON["Three"]["Three"]["Three"] = "HeyHeyHey",
The solution is expected to apply on any similar JSON.

Comment: do you mean how to get value from dictionary by key?

Comment: @John, not a dictionary of dictionaries, it's about getting key name of dictionary storing nested JSON, string completion, new dictionary value passing by using the treated string

Comment: @John, my JSON is deserialized and stored in dictJSON already

Comment: So you don't want a flattened dictionary? `desiredDictionary["key:key:key"] = originalDictionary["key"]["key"]["key"]` kind of makes it sound like you do.

Comment: @Saif, I need a process to get nested key names, passing these key names to strings, and passing the original dictionary value to a new dictionary using those strings as keys

Comment: So you don't want code that just takes JSON like `{ "Two": { "Two": "HeyHey"  } }` and produces a dictionary with a key `Two:Two` and value `HeyHey`?

Comment: @John, my apology that I misunderstood it. And yes, I want my key/value pairs stored in a new flat dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive method to take a JObject and produce a flattened dictionary from it like so:

```
private static IDictionary<string, string> FlattenJObjectToDictionary(JObject obj)
{
    // obtain a key/value enumerable and convert it to a dictionary
    return NestedJObjectToFlatEnumerable(obj, null).ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value);
}

private static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> NestedJObjectToFlatEnumerable(JObject data, string path = null)
{
    // path will be null or a value like Three:Three: (where Three:Three is the parent chain)

    // go through each property in the json object
    foreach (var kv in data.Properties())
    {
        // if the value is another jobject, we'll recursively call this method
        if (kv.Value is JObject)
        {
            var childDict = (JObject)kv.Value;

            // build the child path based on the root path and the property name
            string childPath = path != null ? string.Format("{0}{1}:", path, kv.Name) : string.Format("{0}:", kv.Name);

            // get each result from our recursive call and return it to the caller
            foreach (var resultVal in NestedJObjectToFlatEnumerable(childDict, childPath))
            {
                yield return resultVal;
            }
        }
        else if (kv.Value is JArray)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException("Encountered unexpected JArray");
        }
        else
        {
            // this kind of assumes that all values will be convertible to string, so you might need to add handling for other value types
            yield return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(string.Format("{0}{1}", path, kv.Name), Convert.ToString(kv.Value));
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var json = "{\"One\":\"Hey\",\"Two\":{\"Two\":\"HeyHey\" },\"Three\":{\"Three\":{\"Three\":\"HeyHeyHey\"}}}";
var jObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(json);
var flattened = FlattenJObjectToDictionary(jObj);
```

It takes advantage of [`yield return`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield) to return the results of the recursive call as a single `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` and then returns that as a flat dictionary.

Caveats:

- Arrays in JSON will throw an exception (see `else if (kv.Value is JArray)`)
- The `else` part for handling the actual values assumes that all values are convertible to string using `Convert.ToString(kv.Value)`. If this is not the case, you will have to code for extra scenarios.

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/DYFD32663)

Comment: It works perfectly on my sample JSON and other similar JSON, I'll spend some time studying your code, thanks alot John.